# Quebra de linha automatica textbox multiline form de email C#

Tags: c#, html, webforms

Ola pessoal me ajudem aqui pois já tentei de tudo e não deu certo, Não estou conseguindo fazer a textbox modo multiline enviar a quebra de linha por email no form de contato.

```
ex: 
Ola
Quebra de linha
tudo bem
resultado:
Ola Quebra de linha tudo bem.
```

segue código abaixo.

```
<b>Html</b>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Contato</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/Site.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="Scripts/Contato.js"/>
    <script src="Scripts/Contato.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="formEmail" runat="server">
        <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblNome">Nome:</asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox  runat="server" ID="text_nome"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="text_nome" ErrorMessage="Obrigatório">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblemail">Email</asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text_email"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="text_email" ErrorMessage="Obrigatório">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="subject">Assunto</asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text_assunto"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="text_assunto" ErrorMessage="Obrigatório">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMensagem">lblMensagem</asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text_mensagem" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="161px" Width="355px" ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="text_mensagem" ErrorMessage="Obrigatório">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1">Label</asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="jbEnviar" OnClick="jbEnviar_Click" Width="50px" Text="Enviar"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void jbEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        // Endereco que irá aparecer no e-mail do usuário
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(text_email.Text);
        // Destinatarios do e-mail, para incluir mais de um basta separar por ponto e virgula
        mailMessage.To.Add("email@gmail.com");
        mailMessage.Subject = text_assunto.Text;
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        text_mensagem.Text.Replace("\n", "<br />");

        // Conteudo do corpo do e-mail
        mailMessage.Body = text_mensagem.Text;
        mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        //smtp do e-mail que irá enviar
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtpClient.Port = 587;


        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        //credenciais da conta que utilizará para enviar o e-mail
        smtpClient.Credentials = new
        NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "senha");

        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
    }
```

Comment: desculpem sou novo kkk

Comment: Wellington não sei se ajuda, mas tente colocar todos os textos dentro de tags, tipo asism: `<p>texto</p>`. o P é um elemento de bloco e teoricamente deveria jogar o próximo P para linha de baixo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue um tratamento que já utilizei algumas vezes.

```
    string conteudoTexto =  text_mensagem.Text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br />");

    // Conteudo do corpo do e-mail
    mailMessage.Body = conteudoTexto;
```

Comment: Deu Certo.valeu mano vc e o cara kkkk